# Apply Chosen Select Plugin in Wordpress AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, jquery-chosen

P.S. This question is long as there's lot of code. Thank you for your patience and time. I appreciate it.
I am using [ultimate wp query search filter](http://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-wp-query-search-filter/) plugin on my wordpress site. I would like to use chosen plugin instead of default select boxes. The select boxes already on the page are working perfectly with this code.

```
(function($){
$(".first-ddwn, .second-ddwn, .third-ddwn, .main-ddwn, .posts_ajax select").chosen({
no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!",
width: "50%"
});
})(jQuery);
```

I have changed the result html for AJAX search as mentioned by the plugin author so that I get a dropdown of result posts.

```
add_filter('uwpqsf_result_tempt', 'customize_output', '', 4);
function customize_output($results , $arg, $id, $getdata ){
 // The Query
        global $post;
        $apiclass = new uwpqsfprocess();
         $query = new WP_Query( $arg );
    ob_start();    $result = '';?>
    <form action="<? bloginfo('url'); ?>" method="get"><?php
    echo '<select name="page_id" id="page_id">';
    echo '<option value="">Select</option>';
        // The Loop
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post(); ?>
                            <option value="<? echo $post->ID; ?>"><?php echo the_title(); ?></option>
     <?php   }
   echo '</select>';  
   echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="view" />';
   echo '</form>';
     } else {
                 echo  'no post found';
            }
            /* Restore original Post Data */
            wp_reset_postdata();

    $results = ob_get_clean();        
        return $results;
}
```

However, chosen doesn't get applied to this result dropdown. I have tried the option of using settimeout after the AJAX call as mentioned http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-chosen#comment-29299 but it didn't work. maybe I did it wrong. Also when I run it after ajax call like below, chosen does get applied to the select but is all broken.

```
jQuery.ajax({
             type: 'POST',   
             url: ajax.url,
             timeout:3000,
             data: ({action : 'uwpqsf_ajax',getdata:getdata, pagenum:pagenum }),
             beforeSend:function() {$(''+ajxdiv+'').empty();res.container.append(res.loader);},
             success: function(html) {
                res.container.find(res.loader).remove();
              $(''+ajxdiv+'').html(html);
              $(".content select").chosen();
             }
             });
```

This is what I get
[image][image][image]

This is plugin's uwpqsfscript.js file

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('body').on('click','.usearchbtn', function(e) {
        process_data($(this));
        return false;
    });

    $('body').on('click','.upagievent', function(e) {
        var pagenumber =  $(this).attr('id');
        var formid = $('#curuform').val();
        upagi_ajax(pagenumber, formid);
        return false;
    });

    $('body').on('keypress','.uwpqsftext',function(e) {
      if(e.keyCode == 13){
        e.preventDefault();
        process_data($(this));
      }
    });

    window.process_data = function ($obj) {

        var ajxdiv = $obj.closest("form").find("#uajaxdiv").val();  
        var res = {loader:$('<div />',{'class':'umloading'}),container : $(''+ajxdiv+'')};

        var getdata = $obj.closest("form").serialize();
        var pagenum = '1';

        jQuery.ajax({
             type: 'POST',   
             url: ajax.url,
             timeout:3000,
             data: ({action : 'uwpqsf_ajax',getdata:getdata, pagenum:pagenum }),
             beforeSend:function() {$(''+ajxdiv+'').empty();res.container.append(res.loader);},
             success: function(html) {
                res.container.find(res.loader).remove();
              $(''+ajxdiv+'').html(html);

             }
             });

    }   

    window.upagi_ajax = function (pagenum, formid) {
        var ajxdiv = $(''+formid+'').find("#uajaxdiv").val();   
        var res = {loader:$('<div />',{'class':'umloading'}),container : $(''+ajxdiv+'')};
        var getdata = $(''+formid+'').serialize();

        jQuery.ajax({
             type: 'POST',   
             url: ajax.url,
             data: ({action : 'uwpqsf_ajax',getdata:getdata, pagenum:pagenum }),
             beforeSend:function() {$(''+ajxdiv+'').empty(); res.container.append(res.loader);},
             success: function(html) {
              res.container.find(res.loader).remove();
              $(''+ajxdiv+'').html(html);

            //res.container.find(res.loader).remove();
             }
             });
    }

 $('body').on('click', '.chktaxoall,.chkcmfall',function () {

    $(this).closest('.togglecheck').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);

     });

});//end of script
```

And some relevant code (maybe?) from uwpqsf-process-class.php

```
//front ajax
     add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_uwpqsf_ajax', array($this, 'uwpqsf_ajax') );
     add_action( 'wp_ajax_uwpqsf_ajax', array($this, 'uwpqsf_ajax') );
     add_action( 'pre_get_posts', array($this ,'uwpqsf_search_query'),1000);
    }
function uwpqsf_ajax(){
$postdata =parse_str($_POST['getdata'], $getdata);
$taxo = (isset($getdata['taxo']) && !empty($getdata['taxo'])) ? $getdata['taxo'] : null;
$cmf = (isset($getdata['cmf']) && !empty($getdata['cmf'])) ? $getdata['cmf'] : null;
$formid = $getdata['uformid'];
$nonce =  $getdata['unonce'];
$pagenumber = isset($_POST['pagenum']) ? $_POST['pagenum'] : null;

if(isset($formid) && wp_verify_nonce($nonce, 'uwpsfsearch')){
    $id = absint($formid);
    $options = get_post_meta($id, 'uwpqsf-option', true);
    $cpts = get_post_meta($id, 'uwpqsf-cpt', true);
    $pagenumber = isset($_POST['pagenum']) ? $_POST['pagenum'] : null;
    $default_number = get_option('posts_per_page');

    $cpt        = !empty($cpts) ? $cpts : 'any';
    $ordermeta  = !empty($options[0]['smetekey']) ? $options[0]['smetekey'] : null;
    $ordertype = (!empty($options[0]['otype']) ) ? $options[0]['otype'] : null;
    $order      = !empty($options[0]['sorder']) ? $options[0]['sorder'] : null;
    $number      = !empty($options[0]['resultc']) ? $options[0]['resultc'] : $default_number;

    $keyword = !empty($getdata['skeyword']) ? sanitize_text_field($getdata['skeyword']) : null;
    $get_tax = $this->get_uwqsf_taxo($id, $taxo);
    $get_meta = $this->get_uwqsf_cmf($id, $cmf);

    if($options[0]['snf'] != '1' && !empty($keyword)){
     $get_tax = $get_meta = null;
    }

    $ordermeta  = apply_filters('uwpqsf_ometa_query',$ordermeta,$getdata,$id);
    $ordervalue = apply_filters('uwpqsf_ometa_type',$ordertype,$getdata,$id);
    $order      = apply_filters('uwpqsf_order_query',$order,$getdata,$id);  
    $number     = apply_filters('uwpqsf_pnum_query',$number,$getdata,$id);  



    $args = array(
        'post_type' => $cpt,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_key'=> $ordermeta,
        'orderby' => $ordertype,
        'order' => $order, 
        'paged'=> $pagenumber,
        'posts_per_page' => $number,
        'meta_query' => $get_meta,                      
        'tax_query' => $get_tax,
        's' => esc_html($keyword),
        );

    $arg = apply_filters( 'uwpqsf_query_args', $args, $id,$getdata);        



    $results =  $this->uajax_result($arg, $id,$pagenumber,$getdata);
    $result = apply_filters( 'uwpqsf_result_tempt',$results , $arg, $id, $getdata );    

    echo $result;
    }else{ echo 'There is error here';}
        die;    



 }//end ajax    

  function uajax_result($arg, $id,$pagenumber,$getdata){
        $query = new WP_Query( $arg );
    $html = '';
        //print_r($query);  // The Loop
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
      $html .= '<h1>'.__('Search Results :', 'UWPQSF' ).'</h1>';
       while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                $query->the_post();global $post;
            $html .= '<article><header class="entry-header">'.get_the_post_thumbnail().'';
            $html .= '<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="'.get_permalink().'" rel="bookmark">'.get_the_title().'</a></h1>';
            $html .= '</header>';
            $html .= '<div class="entry-summary">'.get_the_excerpt().'</div></article>';

          }
            $html .= $this->ajax_pagination($pagenumber,$query->max_num_pages, 4, $id,$getdata);
         } else {
                    $html .= __( 'Nothing Found', 'UWPQSF' );
                }
                /* Restore original Post Data */
                wp_reset_postdata();

        return $html;


  }//end result
```

I have been searching for days and have tried many things to make this work. I have no knowledge of jquery,so maybe someone will help me out.
Many Thanks

Comment: Just wondering if anyone has an answer...

Comment: Did you try at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: No I didn't as I have shifted to Select2. I used `$(".content select").select2();` after AJAX success and it works perfectly.